# Undefined Reference to 'vtable for class'

Tags: c++, vtable, visitor-pattern

I am implementing a Visitor class in C++ that generates XML output for a parse tree.

When I compile with Clion on Windows the code compiles but when it runs after it outputs what is expected it crashes.  The error code is this

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

When I try to compile using gcc (without Clion) I get the error message

> Undefined Reference to 'vtable for PrintXMLVisitor'.

My code is the following.  I have distilled it down to the least amount the produces the error

**ASTNode.h**

```
#ifndef MINILANG_ASTNODE_H
#define MINILANG_ASTNODE_H

#include <memory>
class Visitor;

class ASTNode {
public:
    virtual void accept(std::shared_ptr<Visitor> visitor) = 0;
};


#endif //MINILANG_ASTNODE_H
```

**ASTTypeNode.h**

```
#ifndef MINILANG_ASTTYPENODE_H
#define MINILANG_ASTTYPENODE_H


#include "ASTNode.h"

class ASTTypeNode: public ASTNode {
public:
    enum Type {Real, Int, Bool, String};
    ASTTypeNode(Type type);
    Type getType() const;

    void accept(std::shared_ptr<Visitor> visitor) override;

private:
    Type type;
};


#endif //MINILANG_ASTTYPENODE_H
```

**ASTTypeNode.cpp**

```
#include "ASTTypeNode.h"
#include "Visitor.h"

ASTTypeNode::ASTTypeNode(ASTTypeNode::Type type)
    : type(type)
{

}

ASTTypeNode::Type ASTTypeNode::getType() const {
    return type;
}

void ASTTypeNode::accept(std::shared_ptr<Visitor> visitor) {
    visitor->visit(std::shared_ptr<ASTTypeNode>(this));
}
```

**Visitor.h**

```
#ifndef MINILANG_VISITOR_H
#define MINILANG_VISITOR_H

#include <memory>
#include "ASTTypeNode.h"


class Visitor {
public:
    virtual void visit(std::shared_ptr<ASTTypeNode> typeNode) = 0;
};


#endif //MINILANG_VISITOR_H
```

**PrintXMLVisitor.h**

```
#ifndef MINILANG_PRINTXMLVISITOR_H
#define MINILANG_PRINTXMLVISITOR_H


#include "Visitor.h"

class PrintXMLVisitor: public Visitor {
public:
    void visit(std::shared_ptr<ASTTypeNode> typeNode) override;
};


#endif //MINILANG_PRINTXMLVISITOR_H
```

**PrintXMLVisitor.cpp**

```
#include "PrintXMLVisitor.h"
#include <iostream>

void PrintXMLVisitor::visit(std::shared_ptr<ASTTypeNode> typeNode) {

    std::string typeName;
    switch(typeNode->getType())
    {
        case ASTTypeNode::Type::Real:
            typeName = "Real";
            break;
        case ASTTypeNode::Type::Int:
            typeName = "Int";
            break;
        case ASTTypeNode::Type::Bool:
            typeName = "Bool";
            break;
        case ASTTypeNode::Type::String:
            typeName = "String";
            break;
        default:
            typeName = "Error";
            exit(22);
    }

    std::cout << "<TypeNode>" << typeName << "</TypeNode>" << std:: endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Lexer.h"
#include "ASTTypeNode.h"
#include "PrintXMLVisitor.h"

int main() {

    ASTTypeNode astTypeNode (ASTTypeNode::Type::Int);
    astTypeNode.accept(std::make_shared<PrintXMLVisitor>());


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, my fault, browser mistake.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your crafting a shared pointer that isn't dynamic. Specifically,

```
void ASTTypeNode::accept(std::shared_ptr<Visitor> visitor) {
    visitor->visit(std::shared_ptr<ASTTypeNode>(this)); // <=== HERE
}
```

The `this` in that statement refers to:

```
int main() 
{
    ASTTypeNode astTypeNode (ASTTypeNode::Type::Int); // <== this object
    astTypeNode.accept(std::make_shared<PrintXMLVisitor>());
    return 0;
}
```

Changing toolchains isn't going to fix this problem you have options, the two most obvious being:

- Stop using a `std::shared_ptr` for the visit parameter.
- Manage all `ASTNodeType` instances a requiring being `std::shared_ptr` managed and share from `this` using the `std:enable_shared_from_this` capabilities of the standard library.

The former of these is obvious (or at least it is *now*), so I'll not discuss it further. The latter is *not* necessarily trivial, as it mandates any instances of your underlying class that utilize `shared_from_this` must be managed by `std::shared_ptr` wrappers. I.e., there are no concrete constructions like you're currently doing in `main()`. This could have significant impact on your overall code base, so choose this carefully.

An example of how the above would work in your case:

First, change the derivation chain of `ASTNodeType` to look like this:

```
class ASTTypeNode
    : public ASTNode
    , public std::enable_shared_from_this<ASTTypeNode> // ADDED
```

Next, utilize `shared_from_this` as follows:

```
void ASTTypeNode::accept(std::shared_ptr<Visitor> visitor) 
{
    visitor->visit(shared_from_this()); // HERE
}
```

And finally, honor the warrant you've made that `ASTNodeType` instances are shared-ptr managed by doing this:

```
int main() 
{
    std::shared_ptr<ASTTypeNode> astTypeNode = std::make_shared<ASTTypeNode>(ASTTypeNode::Type::Int);
    astTypeNode->accept(std::make_shared<PrintXMLVisitor>());
    return 0;
}
```

That should work. Read more about the things used in the above code here:

- [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)
- [`std::enable_shared_from_this::shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this)

As I said, all of this is to facilitate using a `std::shared_ptr` from an object given only a `this` pointer. If you can remove that requirement in the first place, it may be an easier path to take, and I would consider that first.

Comment: @Frac Good choice. I would have done the same, given the fairly trivial conditions you have =P. Happy reading.

Comment: To the individual that recently down-voted this, anonymous down-voting is *always* FTL. So much for confidence in action. If you down-vote, kindly justify *why* in comments. Otherwise, you're action is considered little more than spite and/or ignorance.